# How to make a yes/no option to control the shown text, using beamer, latex

Tags: beamer, options

I am making template for presentation slides using `beamer` class.

I want to let the user choose if this file is confidential or not. If yes, then shown `it is yes`; if not, then show `it is no`.

The following pseudo-code is what I want to do. Do you know how to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}

\confidential{yes}  % yes or no

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Click} 
\framesubtitle{Click}    

\if\confidential=yes
it is yes
\else
it is no
\fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `multiaudience` package or maybe LaTeX's if mechanism (`\newif\ifconfidential` and then `\ifconfidential`).

Comment: Related: [How to exclude text portions by simply setting a variable or option?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/28096)